# Safari is not running Javascript function at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

So I am attempting to create a menu that has dynamically generated padding(left and right) for each menu item so if the user resizes the browser then the menu items list does not spill over onto a second line. Below is the code that I have written to do this. And the code works just fine But not everything works smoothly in Safari. When you load the page in Safari, the script has no effect. It's only once I begin to resize my browser does the script run and change the padding widths. This does not happen on any other browser.

```
//autowidth for menu items
function setMenuWidth() {

    var fullWidth = $('.main-navigation').width();
    var numElements = $('.main-navigation > ul > li > a').length;
    var contentWidth = 0, differenceWidth, paddingWidth;

    $('.main-navigation > ul > li > a').each(function(){
        contentWidth += $(this).width();
    });

    differenceWidth = fullWidth - contentWidth;
    paddingWidth = (differenceWidth/numElements)/2;

    $('.main-navigation > ul > li > a').css('padding-left', paddingWidth + 'px');
    $('.main-navigation > ul > li > a').css('padding-right', paddingWidth + 'px');

}
setMenuWidth();
```

As you can see I created the function and then called it immediately after.
And then in order to make it run on resize, I have called a resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    scrollToResults();
    setMenuWidth();
});
```

I hope I have been as clear as possible. Has anyone ran into this issue before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you're calling the `setMenuWidth()` function *after* DOMReady has fired, eg: `$(function() { setMenuWidth(); });`

Comment: Is the script in the page *after* the elements it refers to?  If not then they don't exist when you run it.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be working now. I simply moved the location of the resize event closer to the bottom of the page. Thanks!